# askopenfilename handling cancel on dialogue

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a gui which initializes the askopenfilename when a button is pressed but I want to be able to account for when the user selects cancel on the askopenfilename dialogue

Here is my function to handle the clicked button yet the if statement line doesnt seem to work!

```
def openFileClicked(self):
  self.filename=filedialog.askopenfilename()
  if self.filename== None: 
        self.e.config(state= NORMAL)
        self.e.delete(0,END)
        self.e.insert(0,"...")
        self.e.config(state="readonly")
  self.e.config(state= NORMAL)
  self.e.delete(0,END)
  self.e.insert(0, self.filename)
  self.e.config(state="readonly")
  print ((self.filename))
```

Comment: You're doing the same thing both inside the if statement and outside the if statement with the exception of the `self.e.insert` line.  What exactly is the problem you're having?  (As an aside, the canonical way to check for `None` is to use `is None` instead of `== None`.  It doesn't make a huge difference in most cases but the former is more likely to be correct (and is much, much faster).

Answer (score 10):

`.askopenfilename()` returns an empty string on cancel, not None.  So you can either compare to `''` or `False`.  For the sake of having a code sample:

```
def openFileClicked(self):
    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if not self.filename:
        # config...delete...etc.
    # Rest of function
```

At least that's how I'd do it, you may have your own preferences.

Comment: is that possible that I can able to browse the files of remote machine through askopenfilename or other command

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a few years later but I found a quirk that is related and couldn't find any information. Hope the information is useful to anyone who comes across this answer.

Basically, as stated, clicking **Cancel** will return an empty string...
Unless you actually select/highlight a file first and then click cancel.
This seems to return an empty tuple!!!

Using python 2.6.6 (IDK, ask RedHat)
Running the following code produces the subsequent results

`f_picked = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
test = type(f_picked)
print (test)`
Results:
`<type 'unicode'>` # Nothing selected, **Cancel** clicked
`<type 'tuple'>` # File selected, **Cancel** clicked
`<type 'str'>` # File selected, **OK** clicked
`<type 'tuple'>` # Multiple files selected, **OK** clicked

Answer (score 0):

you can account for user selection of cancel as show below:

```
def openFileClicked(self):
    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    # When user select cancel
    if (len(self.filename) == 0): 
        # put your code here in case the user selected cancel
    
    # Otherwise the user selected a file
    else:
        # put your code here in case the user selected a file
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for an empty string will not work if the [initialdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html) argument is used because cancel will still assign the value `Path('.')` to the variable. The best I can think of is to just keep asking until they pick a location. This unfortunately puts them into a loop, so use your best judgement if that's better than continuing the code with a false location.

```
while folder == Path('.'):
    folder = Path(askdirectory(title='Select Folder', initialdir='.'))
```