# How to retain the path of selected file once we pressed the cancel button in askopenfilename

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()` for performing the browse option in my GUI. It works well. But I have a new scenario to be implemented.

I understood that `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()` works in such a way that if we select the file and press the **OPEN** button then this returns the selected filename that correspond to existing file of type `str`.

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir =  "/", title = "Select File", filetype =
    (("doc files","*.doc"),) )
    print("Filename - ",filename) #prints the path of the selected file here
```

And if we press the **CANCEL** button by mistake after selecting the file then it returns an empty string in my case and I think this is intended as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010461/askopenfilename-handling-cancel-on-dialogue). Here comes the scenario. I want to retain the path of selected file once we pressed the **CANCEL** button in `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()`. I know that cancelling means we don't need that. But our scenario is different.

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir =  "/", title = "Select File", filetype =
    (("doc files","*.doc"),) )
    print("Filename - ",filename) #Here I want to get the path of the selected file once we pressed the CANCEL button
```

> I am not sure about the feasibility of this scenario. Is it possible
> to implement this scenario ? I am open to use some other function if
> exists.

Please guide me to achieve this part.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you want with the standard dialogs. They are explicitly designed to return an empty string if you press the cancel button. There is no mechanism for getting what might have been selected.

If you want that type of behavior, you will need to create your own file dialog.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan: In the statement that you have mentioned `you will need to create your own file dialog.`. How this can be done ? Any link can you refer to me ?